# how to retrieve from android /iOS device to Kafka producer API Spark stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

I need to save stream data to may Casandra DB using Kafka spark stream. I have implemented Kafka consumer and producer set and connect it to spark and save the date to my db.now I don't know how to retrieve data from client devices like Android and iOS to receive data to the Kafka producer

I implement Kafka spark set up using [Link description here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)

Comment: What task are you planning to solve?

Comment: we need to read-write data from Cassandra through spark in spring boot application, we are doing this combination for performing analytics